# php imagecopyresized vs imagecopyresampled vs imagecopy pros/cons

Tags: php, image, copy, gd

These all seem to do the same thing.
What are the pros/cons of each.

imagecopyresized() vs imagecopyresampled() vs imagecopy().

I'm resizing a user submitted image.

So I have an image shell created with '$newImage=imagecreatetruecolor(250, 250)'.

And now I want to copy the orginal image into the '$newImage'

Answer (score 116, accepted):

[imagecopyresized](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresized) will copy and scale and image. This uses a fairly primitive algorithm that tends to yield more pixelated results.

[imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresampled) will copy and scale and image, it uses a smoothing and pixel interpolating algorithm that will generally yield much better results than imagecopyresized at the cost of a little cpu usage.

[imagecopy](http://www.php.net/imagecopy) will copy but will not scale the image.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and precise answer. Do you know of any difference in performance and/or quality with the imagescale() function?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the cost of a little cpu usage"? More than `imagecopyresized` I assume?